# Error in linear model when values are 0

Tags: r, error-handling, lm

I have a data set that has names, value 1, and value 2.  I need to run a regression and obtain the t-statistic for each of the names.  I got help on StackOverflow in constructing the linear model.  I noticed that sometimes I get data that's 0's.  It's OK and I want the model to keep running and not bomb.  However, when the 0's are in there, the linear model bombs.

```
    v1<-rnorm(1:50)
    v2<-rnorm(1:50)
    data<-data.frame(v1,v2)
    data[1:50,"nm"]<-"A"
    data[50:100,"nm"]<-"B"
    data[50:100,"v1"]<-0
    data[50:100,"v2"]<-0
    data<-data[c("nm","v1","v2")]

    ## run regression and generate universe
    plyrFunc <- function(x){
      mod <- lm(v1~v2, data = x)
      return(summary(mod)$coefficients[2,3])
    }

    lm <- ddply(data, .(nm), plyrFunc)
```

As you can see, for name B, since everything is 0, the model bombs.  I cannot just remove all 0's because often times the values are indeed 0.

I don't know how to edit the above code so that it keeps going.

Can anyone let me know?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The model actually works fine, it is a subsetting of `summary(mod)$coefficients` that throws you an error because it contains only one row in the all-zeroes case:

```
> summary(lm(v1~v2,data[data$nm=="A",]))$coefficients
              Estimate Std. Error    t value  Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -0.1462766  0.1591779 -0.9189503 0.3628138
v2          -0.1315238  0.1465024 -0.8977590 0.3738900

> summary(lm(v1~v2,data[data$nm=="B",]))$coefficients
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)        0          0     NaN      NaN
```

Thus, you need to modify your function to take this case into account:

```
plyrFunc <- function(x){
  mod <- lm(v1~v2, data = x)
  res <- summary(mod)$coefficients
  if (nrow(res)>1) res[2,3] else NA
}

library(plyr)
result <- ddply(data, .(nm), plyrFunc)
```

Output for your sample data set:

```
  nm         V1
1  A -0.1825896
2  B         NA
```